# How to show an extra field in 'Items Ordered' table in Order Details page - Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have a custom attribute for each product in Magento.

I want to show that for each product in 'Items Ordered' table in order details page of Magento dashboard.

I am unable to find the PHP file that. What is location of that file?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to show admin path in admin in magento 
You can do it by changing the database directly. If you have something like phpMyAdmin that is a good way to gain access. Enter this SQL.

INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`)
      VALUES ('websites', '0', 'dev/debug/template_hints', '1');

When you are done with path hints just delete the matching record from core_config_data Or update the value field to 0 instead of deleting the whole record, it will probably be the last one since you've just added it.

File you are looking is

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\baab.bh\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\view\items\renderer\default.phtml
```